# Sharepoint 2013 provider hosted app using Profile Service getting an errorwhile checking prerequisites for an app

Tags: sharepoint

Interestingly I am able to install the app on mysites but not on a different publishing portal site.
When I try to add it I get the following meesage
Sorry, this app is not supported on your server.

The app tries to call UserProfile Service. The appmanifest.xml has the following permissions

AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" 
    AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" 
    AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" 
    AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="FullControl" 
    AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/core" Right="FullControl" 
    AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/microfeed" Right="FullControl" 
    AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" 
  AppPermissionRequest

```
Caught a SPException while checking prerequisites for App 'Address' with asset id '': Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: An error has been encountered while checking prerequisites for an app. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: name    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ThrowArgumentExceptionWithTraceTag(UInt32 tagId, ULSCat traceCategory, String argumentName, String argumentLocalizedMessage, String traceMessage, Type argumentExceptionType)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ThrowArgumentExceptionWithTraceTag(UInt32 tagId, ULSCat traceCategory, String argumentName, Type argumentExceptionType)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCapability..ctor(String name, SPCapabilityStatus capabilityStatus, String message)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SPSocialPermissionProvider.GetMissingCustomDependencies(Uri permissionRequestScope, SPWeb hostWeb)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppPermissionProvider.GetMissingDependencies(Uri permissionRequestScope, SPAppPrerequisitesCheckingContext context, Boolean shouldLog)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.SPAppPrerequisitesChecker.CheckPermissionScopeDependencies(List`1 permissionScopeList, Boolean shouldLog)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.SPAppPrerequisitesChecker.CheckPermissionScopeDependencies(List`1 permissionScopeList, Boolean shouldLog)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.SPAppPrerequisitesChecker.Check(SPAppMetadata appMetadata, List`1& missingCapabilities, Boolean shouldLog)




Caught an exception while on calling SPCapabilityChecker.GetMissingCapabilities(): System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: name    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ThrowArgumentExceptionWithTraceTag(UInt32 tagId, ULSCat traceCategory, String argumentName, String argumentLocalizedMessage, String traceMessage, Type argumentExceptionType)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ThrowArgumentExceptionWithTraceTag(UInt32 tagId, ULSCat traceCategory, String argumentName, Type argumentExceptionType)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCapability..ctor(String name, SPCapabilityStatus capabilityStatus, String message)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SPSocialPermissionProvider.GetMissingCustomDependencies(Uri permissionRequestScope, SPWeb hostWeb)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppPermissionProvider.GetMissingDependencies(Uri permissionRequestScope, SPAppPrerequisitesCheckingContext context, Boolean shouldLog)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.SPAppPrerequisitesChecker.CheckPermissionScopeDependencies(List`1 permissionScopeList, Boolean shouldLog)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you make the effort to format the stacktrace, so that it's more readable?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the permissions to the following and it is working now. It appears that it was not finding some social list in the site ( publishing site)

```
AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" 
AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"
AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" 
AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" AppPermissionRequest
```